# Dynamically calculated center of mass

Tags: animation, physics

The center of mass changes for an organic object when it moves its body parts. Because Center of Mass is key thing with physically correct animation is how to get the center of mass dynamically?

Such a thing is implemented in the application https://cascadeur.com/, but I would like to have everything at hand in Blender.